# Aggregration of nested objects with filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm not sure what is wrong with this query, but I can't figure out the solution, and would appreciate your insight. I am trying to do aggregration of nested object with filter query. I want to get count of field objects where `fields.name` is `AMORTIZED_COST`. Somehow aggregration doesn't return any count. I do get actual document in main search query - which returns 4 document but there are total 6 field rows which matches `AMORTIZED_COST` criteria, so in aggregation I was expecting it will show me 6 rows. Thanks in advance for your help.

FYI - I am using ES 1.5

I am sharing partial type mapping

```
   "templ01": {
      "mappings": {
         "tempobjects": {
            "properties": {
               "description": {
                  "type": "string"
               },
               "fields": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "objid": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
               "formulas": {
                  "type": "nested",
                  "properties": {
                     "formula": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "id": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "name": {
                        "type": "string"
                     },
                     "objid": {
                        "type": "string"
                     }
                  }
               },
```

Here is the search query

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "match_all" : { }
      },
      "filter" : {
        "query" : {
          "nested" : {
            "query" : {
              "match" : {
                "fields.name" : {
                  "query" : "AMORTIZED_COST",
                  "type" : "boolean"
                }
              }
            },
            "path" : "fields",
            "inner_hits" : {
              "name" : "fields"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "fields" : "_sourceall",
  "aggregations" : {
    "3ztDl2iVtc" : {
      "nested" : {
        "path" : "fields"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "filter6yXyIpHISm" : {
          "filters" : {
            "filters" : [ {
              "query" : {
                "match" : {
                  "name" : {
                    "query" : "AMORTIZED_COST",
                    "type" : "boolean"
                  }
                }
              }
            } ]
          },
          "aggregations" : {
            "groupIBa1xQNOuK" : {
              "terms" : {
                "field" : "fields.name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The below is the output.

```
"aggregations": {
      "3ztDl2iVtc": {
         "doc_count": 282,
         "filter6yXyIpHISm": {
            "buckets": [
               {
                  "doc_count": 0,
                  "groupIBa1xQNOuK": {
                     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                     "buckets": []
                  }
               }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your aggregation filter you need to match on `fields.name` and not only on `name` since the filter is inside a `nested` aggregation:

```
  ...
  "aggregations" : {
    "3ztDl2iVtc" : {
      "nested" : {
        "path" : "fields"
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "filter6yXyIpHISm" : {
          "filters" : {
            "filters" : [ {
              "query" : {
                "match" : {
                  "fields.name" : {              <--- change this
                    "query" : "AMORTIZED_COST",
                    "type" : "boolean"
                  }
                }
              }
            } ]
          },
          "aggregations" : {
            "groupIBa1xQNOuK" : {
              "terms" : {
                "field" : "fields.name"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```